# undefined methods appDevDebugProjectContainer Listener Symfony 2.1.8

Tags: symfony, listener

i try to do a custom listener with onKernelRequest, but i have this error 
Fatal error: Call to undefined method appDevDebugProjectContainer::generate()

my service is:

```
services:
kernel.listener.Configurazione:
    class: My\ConfigurazioneBundle\Listener\Configurazione 
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
    arguments: [@security.context,@router,@service_container]
```

my Listener is:

```
namespace My\ConfigurazioneBundle\Listener;

use My\ConfigurazioneBundle\Event\ConfigurazioneEvent;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

class Configurazione {

    protected $sicurezza;
    protected $router;
    protected $container;

    function __construct(SecurityContextInterface $securityContext, $container, $router) {
        $this->sicurezza = $securityContext;
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {

        $user = $this->sicurezza->getToken()->getUser();
        $container = $this->container;
        $url = $this->router->generate('homepage');
    }

}
```

i have this error

Fatal error: Call to undefined method appDevDebugProjectContainer::generate()

my composer.json

```
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.1.8",
        "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.1.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*@dev",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.1.*",
        "kriswallsmith/assetic": "1.1.*@dev",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "dev-master",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "*",
        "punkave/symfony2-file-uploader-bundle":"*",
        "willdurand/expose-translation-bundle": "dev-master",
        "apy/jsfv-bundle":"dev-master",
        "cypresslab/compass-elephant-bundle":"dev-master",
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Configurazione` class you have three arguments: security context, service container and the rounter. In the services you entered [@security.context,@router,@service_container] in the wrong order.

So, PHP tries to execute `generate` method of the `Container` class, not the `Router` class

It's always better to define argument types to avoid that kind of errors. In your case it should be:

```
public function __construct(SecurityContextInterface $securityContext, ContainerInterface $container, RouterInterface $router)
```

You can also just pass the container and get corresponding services from the constructor:

```
public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
{
    $this->router = $container->get('router');
    $this->securityContext = $container->get('security.context');
}
```

Comment: when i do 
$container = $this->container;
$url = $this->router->generate('homepage');

my page dosen't find js and css, i use assetic

Comment: Maybe it was a "good practise" once upon a time but passing whole Container as an argument is considered as "bad practise" nowadays.